# Swift submodules - what are they exactly

Tags: swift, module, package

Coming from the Java world, I cannot still understand exactly what Swift submodules are and are not in terms of Java packages' counterparts.

- How Swift modules and submodules relate to jars and packages in the Java
  world?
- Can you actually import from submodules, e.g. by writing **import
  Module.Submodule1(...).SubmoduleN.MyClass**?
- Are submodules bound to directory trees, just like Java packages? If they are not, then how, where are submodules defined?

(I have not been able to find answers to these questions neither on Apple's online specification of Swift nor in the free book distributed by them. I've asked on some dev lists but the info I got there is in contradiction with Apple's documentation for the Package Manager, especially regarding the third point.)

Comment: @Martijn Pieters - I have added a pair of words.

I mostly disagree with your critics. This question is asking, basically, how the Swift module system maps (conceptually) into the Java packages/jar model.

Logical mappings between models need several sub-questions to pose useful, complete theories. This is not an opinion of mine but a basic fact.

I can delete some of the sub-questions but then my inquiry will lose completeness.

Comment: Furthermore: just as you can judge from the (accepted by me as an OP) answer, it is not only specific and consistent enough, but also not "too broad".

I suggest you to re-think your critics a bit deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Swift module** equivalent to **Java package**, **Swift framework** is like **Java jar**. Submodule is just module inside of other module.
- Yes you can, but it if you want to import just a class you have to use `import class` (`import struct` for struct, `import enum` for `enum`). Simple `import` can be used only with modules.
- No, they're not bound to the folder trees. They're defined using [`Clang module` system](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html), Xcode and SPM perform most of the boilerplate for you.

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer. To make sure I have understood you well, please confirm that the following is true: 1 - neither modules or submodules are bound to the source folder tree, so I can refactor the source folders without breaking my clients' imports; and 2 - submodules are defined not implicitely in any way by the source layout, but by additional tooling and meta-files. Is all this correct?

Comment: In Xcode source files can be anywhere, file belongs to module if it's in the target defining module. In SPM it's somewhat stricter, like source must be in subfolder of the folder with package description, and each target in own folder(though file-system aliases work too). So: for Xcode both are true, for SPM: not really.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot!